# Changing Phpmyadmin Database Structure and Browse Tables View (Vertrigo)

Tags: php, user-interface, phpmyadmin, wamp

I've recently updated my Vertrigo Serv from 2.30 to 2.31. But there's something off about the appearance of my Phpmyadmin. Here are the links to the pictures:

*--Sorry I can't show them because of the reputation*

**The data are shown by column and the table names are duplicated on the top and side**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4wKv.png

**Double Header**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDXuF.png

I uninstalled the prev. ver., removed configs then installed the new one. Already tried every possible changes in the settings.
Maybe you've encountered this even with diff. server, your help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The strange thing here is that this is happening even though you changed the settings and cleared your configuration. Those are settings, but they're stored in `config.inc.php` (or the phpMyAdmin configuration storage, if you use the Settings tab to change them) and if you reset the configurations there, the settings should return to the default (which is set in `libraries/config.inc.php` which shouldn't be edited itself).

What phpMyAdmin version do you have? Is your phpMyAdmin installed by your package manager (aptitude, rpm, synaptic, etc) or did you install it manually?

Can you try downloading again from http://www.phpmyadmin.net and set it up in another folder to see if the problem continues?

Go to the main page of phpMyAdmin, then the "Settings" tab, then the "Main panel" and "Browse mode" tabs. Check the setting for "Repeat headers" and "Default display direction" -- does the text have a yellow background or white? Is there a faint arrow behind it like in this picture:

[image]

Can you paste here your entire `config.inc.php`, obfuscating any sensitive information such as hostnames or passwords? Do you have a "phpmyadmin" or "pmadb" database?

**EDIT:** It occurs to me that I may be making this more complex than it needs to be. When you say you removed the config, what exactly did you do? What specific settings did you change when you tried changing the settings for these two values?